# Raspberry Pi receives its own sent USART bytes (pyserial)

Tags: uart

I have an understanding question about the USART interface on the Raspberry Pi, in connection with the library pyserial 3.4 (https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/).

After the bytes have been sent out of the Raspberry Pi, the bytes that are sent out must not be caught again, otherwise data sent by other controllers will be misinterpreted because the Raspberry Pi has received its own bytes.

I broke down the problem to show what I'm about. Whenever the USART interface transmits a byte (TX), this byte will be directly captured by the receiver in the next step (RX). How can I prevent this?

```
import serial

uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", timeout=1, baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE)

def transmitUART8bit(data):
    uart.write(data.to_bytes(1, byteorder="big"))

def readUART(cnt):
    return int.from_bytes(uart.read(cnt), byteorder='big')

transmitUART8bit(123)
print(readUART(1))
```

**OUTPUT:** 
   `123`

Many thanks and best regards

Comment: It looks like you have either 1) connected the output GPIO to the input GPIO or 2) turned on echo at the remote end.  You need to show the connections and tell us about the software running on both ends of the link.

Comment: For testing i disconnected all the peripheral behind the UART-GPIO pins.

Comment: ALL relevant information should be part of the question.

Comment: I should also point out that /dev/ttyAMA0 may not even be connected to the UART.  That depends on the Pi model and software version.

Comment: If it is not connected to the uart, there would be no output of TX, right?